# Sidekiq not processing jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, background-process, sidekiq

Am using Sidekiq to process background jobs. For some reason my sidekiq workers was stops executing while running any worker. When i restart the sidekiq again, Its not processing the jobs which was processed earlier.

For Example:

I have 10 workers to process the job. I had 5 concurrent process. So its executing first five workers, while this process sidekiq was gets stopped. So the jobs are not completed. When i restart the sidekiq its processing the jobs (5-10). Its not processing the first 5 jobs.

I want to process the remaining jobs(1-5).

Can any one give me the solution?

Comment: hi, check to see, is redis server running?

Comment: @SachinSingh Yes my redis server is up and running. Its processing the jobs(6-10). Its not taking the jobs(1-5) only